# Eliminate Indentations in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, google-api

I'm using the Google Docs API to retrieve the contents of a document and process it using Python. However, the document is of complex structure and I have to loop through multiple nodes of the returned JSON, so I have to use **multiple for loops** to get the desired content and do the filter necessary. Is there a way that I can eliminate some of the indentations to make the format look much more organized?

Here is a snippet of my loops:

```py
for key, docContent in docs_api_result.json().items():
    if key == "body":
        content = docContent['content']
        for i, body_content in enumerate(content):
            if "table" in body_content:
                for sKey, tableContent in content[i]['table'].items():
                    if sKey == "tableRows":
                        for tableRowContent in tableContent:
                            for tableCellMain in tableRowContent['tableCells']:
                                for tableCellContent in tableCellMain['content']:
                                    hasBullet = False
                                    for tableCellElement in tableCellContent['paragraph']['elements']:
                                        if "bullet" in tableCellContent['paragraph']:
                                            ...
```

I know that instead of having

```py
if True:
    # some code here
```

I can replace it with

```py
if False:
    continue
# some code here
```

to remove some of the indents, but that only solves part of the problem. I still have 7 for-loops left and I hope that I could remove some of the indentations as well.

Any help is appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general method for reducing indentation levels would be to identify blocks of code to go in their own functions.

E.g. looking at your loop, I guess I would try something like:

```py
class ApiResultProcessor(object):
    def process_api_result(self, api_result):
        doc_dict = api_result.json()
        if "body" in doc_dict:
            self.process_body(doc_dict["body"])

    def process_body(self, body_dict):
        content = body_dict["content"]
        for i, content_element_dict in enumerate(content):
            if "table" in content_element_dict:
                self.process_table(content_element_dict["table"])
        ...
    

    def process_table(self, table_dict):
        for tableRowContent in table_dict["tableRows"]:
            for tableCellMain in tableRowContent["tableCells"]:
                for tableCellContent in tableCellMain['content']:
                    self.process_cell_content(tableCellContent)

    def process_cell_content(self, table_cell_dict):
        hasBullet = False
        for tableCellElement in table_cell_dict["paragraph"]["elements"]:
            if "bullet" in table_cell_dict["paragraph"]:
                ...
```

The only refactoring that I have done is trying to avoid the dreadful ["for if" antipattern](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20111227-00/?p=8793).

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! It made the styling a lot better :)

Answer (score -1):

I am not that experienced with python, but I am pretty sure you can use only one space and not multiple of four every indentation and it won't be an indentation error. Although it is not according to the PEP 8 protocol...
So just remove every 4 spaces/tab you have in this bunch of code, to 1 space.

Comment: You *can* technically use only 1 space for indentation, but that does not solve the readability issue.

Comment: Well of course it's better to split into functions, I just wanted to say eliminate spaces is an option, you can leave only 1 and not 4 spaces :)